# How to correctly use pandas sort_index with level and axis arguments?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Regarding this df:

```
               Amount                          type                 
Month_year 2019-06-01     2019-07-01     2019-06-01    2019-07-01   
TYPE_ID             1   2          1   2          1  2          1  2
ID                                                                  
100                20  10         40  20          1  1          2  1
200                80  60         30  10          2  2          1  1
```

The following code:

```
df = df.sort_index(axis=1, level=[1,2])
```

produces this:

```
               Amount       type     Amount  ...       type     Amount       type
Month_year 2019-06-01 2019-06-01 2019-06-01  ... 2019-07-01 2019-07-01 2019-07-01
TYPE_ID             1          1          2  ...          1          2          2
ID                                           ...                                 
100                20          1         10  ...          2         20          1
200                80          2         60  ...          1         10          1
```

I really don't understand what's going on. I've read [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) but there are no examples and the description is really obscure.

Could anyone explain to me how this method works and how I received this result?

Comment: It is sortng the columns, first sort by level = 1  (Month year), after alphabetically by level 2

Comment: @ansev thanks. And what about the axis? Why when axis=0 the dataframe remains the same? What exactly does it do?

Comment: `axis = 0`, sort by the index

Comment: @ansev I don't understand. Could you elaborate more please?

Comment: The index here is ID that goes 100 and 200, and the dataset seems already sorted by the index. Sorting an already sorted dataset doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Hurried-Helpful the rows are sorted by the index, but ansev said that it is sorting the columns. I don't understand how it's possible to sort the columns by the index.

Comment: The row are sorted by the index when `axis = 0`, but when `axis = 1`, they are sorted by the columns. The dataframe is already sorted index-wise. That's why sorting with `axis = 0` does nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essentially,

**`sort_index` with `axis=1` sorts the column headers, and this ordering is then used to set the order of the columns.**

And, the corollary,

**`sort_index` with `axis=0` sorts the index, and this ordering is then used to set the order of the rows.**

---

This is what your input `df` looks like:

[image]

The top three "rows" in the picture above correspond to a pandas MultiIndex column of `df`, which looks like this:

```
df.columns
MultiIndex([('Amount', '2019-06-01', 1),
            ('Amount', '2019-06-01', 2),
            ('Amount', '2019-07-01', 1),
            ('Amount', '2019-07-01', 2),
            (  'type', '2019-06-01', 1),
            (  'type', '2019-06-01', 2),
            (  'type', '2019-07-01', 1),
            (  'type', '2019-07-01', 2)])
```

Let's pretend your 3-level multiIndex column is magically converted into a DataFrame which each level its own column called `cdf`:

```
cdf
    level_0     level_1  level_2
(1)  Amount  2019-06-01        1
(2)  Amount  2019-06-01        2
(3)  Amount  2019-07-01        1
(4)  Amount  2019-07-01        2
(5)    type  2019-06-01        1
(6)    type  2019-06-01        2
(7)    type  2019-07-01        1
(8)    type  2019-07-01        2
```

The row numbers here correspond to the column identifiers in the original DataFrame. Let's see what happens when we sort `cdf` by the last two columns:

```
cdf.sort_values(['level_1', 'level_2'])

    level_0     level_1  level_2
(1)  Amount  2019-06-01        1
(5)    type  2019-06-01        1
(2)  Amount  2019-06-01        2
(6)    type  2019-06-01        2
(3)  Amount  2019-07-01        1
(7)    type  2019-07-01        1
(4)  Amount  2019-07-01        2
(8)    type  2019-07-01        2
```

Notice the index of the sorted `cdf`:

```
(1) (5) (2) (6) (3) (7) (4) (8)
```

Now let's see what happens when we apply the `sort_index` operation to `df`:

```
df.sort_index(level=[1, 2], axis=1)
```

[image]

The ellipses in the center indicate that not all columns can be displayed due to the width of the terminal (in fact, columns (6) and (3) are not displayed but they are there very much there), but that's not the interesting part. Contrast the column ordering here with the row ordering of sorted `cdf`, you'll see these are are identical.